# Raspberry pi omxplayer wrapper + Gpio

Tags: wrapper, omxplayer

Omxplayer crashes after pushbuttons 
I like to change movies with pushbuttons and this is code that I have so far but Omxplayer crashes after few pushbutton are push!
I am new to raspberry pi and python been looking for a fix but cannot find any. Any help is welcome.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mygpio.py", line 34, in <module>
    player.load(vida)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/omxplayer/player.py", line 162, in load
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/omxplayer/player.py", line 88, in _load_source
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/omxplayer/player.py", line 134, in _setup_dbus_connection
SystemError: DBus cannot connect to the OMXPlayer process
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os.path
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import os
from omxplayer import OMXPlayer
vida = '/home/pi/Videos/testvids/6.mov'
vidb = '/home/pi/Videos/testvids/3.mov'
vidc = '/home/pi/Videos/testvids/t2.mp4'
default = '/home/pi/Videos/testvids/t1.mp4'

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO



#set up GPIO using BCM numbering

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#All Gpio's as input and pull up

GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)


player = OMXPlayer(default,args=['--no-osd','--blank'],)

while True:

      if GPIO.input(2) ==0:

           player.load(vida)
           print("gpio 2")
           player.play()
           #sleep(5)

      if (GPIO.input(3) == 0):

            player.load(vidb)
            print("gpio 3")
            player.play()
           # sleep(5)



      if (GPIO.input(4) == 0):
            player.load(vidc)
            print("gpio 4")
            player.play()
            #sleep(5)



GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I'm having the same issues - have you gotten past this?

Answer (score 0):

looks like this was a bug in the wrapper

https://github.com/willprice/python-omxplayer-wrapper/issues/85